# $\sin(\theta) = \frac{\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}}{R}$, what is $\frac{d\theta}{dx} \left( \sin \theta \right)$?

Tags: calculus

I'm given $\sin(\theta) = \frac{\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}}{R}$, and I would like to find $\frac{d\theta}{dx} (\sin \theta)$.

I'm a little confused by this notation, because if it was simply $\frac{d}{dx}(\sin \theta)$, then I would have

$$
\frac{d}{dx} (\sin \theta) = \frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}}{R} \right)
= \frac{-x}{R\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}}
$$

But what is
$$
\frac{d\theta}{dx} \left( \frac{\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}}{R} \right)
$$
?

Comment: $\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}x}=(\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\theta})^{-1}$ and you multiply it by $\sin\theta$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

$$\sin(\theta)=\frac{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}{R}\implies$$

$$\cos(\theta)\frac{d\theta}{dx}=\frac{-x}{R\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}$$

with

$$\cos(\theta)=\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\theta)}$$
$$=\pm \sqrt{1-\frac{R^2-x^2}{R^2}}=\pm \frac xR$$

thus

$$\frac{d\theta}{dx}=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}$$

and
$$\sin(\theta)\frac{d\theta}{dx}=\pm\frac{ 1}{R}$$

Comment: Is $\frac{d}{d\theta}$ and $\frac{d\theta}{dx}$ of $\frac{\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}}{R}$ the same thing?

Comment: $$\frac{d}{dx}=\frac{d}{d\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dx}$$ this is the chain rule.

Comment: But isn't $\frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}}{R} \right) = \frac{-x}{R\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}}$?

Comment: @student010101 Yes, but what is $\frac{ d \sin(\theta)}{dx}$

Comment: Should that be $\frac{d}{d\theta} \frac{d\theta}{dx} \sin(\theta)$?

Comment: But here I just plugged in the chain rule for $\frac{d}{dx} = \frac{d}{d\theta} \frac{d\theta}{dx}$. I have not differentiated yet?

Comment: @student010101 Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: So I have $\frac{d \sin \theta}{dx} = \frac{d\theta}{dx} \frac{d \sin \theta}{d\theta} = \frac{d\theta}{dx} \cos \theta$

Comment: @student010101 Yes. that is what i wrote in my answer.

Comment: Ah so I was confused because I saw some notation in my notes that said $\frac{d\theta}{dx} (\sin \theta)$. I misinterpreted this. I believe this is just say $\frac{d \theta}{dx}$ times $\sin \theta$. I had thought it was saying we differentiate $\sin \theta$ using $\frac{d\theta}{dx}$ which doesn't really make sense

Comment: @student010101 is it ok ?